# Why i can't insert data to my database?

Tags: java, database

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class VeriTabani 
{        
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String numara=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Öğrenci no giriniz:");

        String ad=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Öğrenci adı:");

        String soyad=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Öğrenci soyadı:");
        String bolum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bölüm :");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/deneme","root","");
        Statement ifade = conn.createStatement();

        ifade.executeUpdate("Insert into ogrenci " + " (id , ad , soyad , bolum , numara)" + "values("+ad+"','"+soyad+"','"+bolum+"','"+numara+"')");           
     }
}
```

Comment: Could we have the database schema, and more importantly the reason why it does not work?

Comment: Please improve your question. Have you got any error message ?

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement list five columns, but provides only four values. Either provide a value for `id` or remove it from the column list.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, `id` should not be in the query because it will be set by the database.

You want to insert 5 values `(id,ad,soyad,bolum,numara)` but you give only 4 of them `values(ad,soyad,bolum,numara)`.

Also, and this is not related to your question, but you should really use `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ogrenci(ad,soyad,bolum,numara) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
preparedStatement.setString(1,ad);
preparedStatement.setString(2,soyad);
preparedStatement.setString(3,bolum);
preparedStatement.setString(4,numara);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have to create a transaction or set auto-commit true.

After this

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/deneme","root","");
```

try

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```